# How do I get my follower to stop following me when I do not know where they are?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am trying to get Faendal back as a follower, but he says I already have a follower. I am pretty sure I do but can't find him. The follower I'm trying to get rid of is Windhelm's house Carl. I've tried to wait and see if he decides to become bored and leave, I've also tried to check my houses, I've fast traveled and even that doesn't work.

I'm on Xbox One, no mods. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Might be a glitch, for me Lydia was gone for several days few times, but always got back to my house eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned you've already tried fast traveling and that does not work, which is typically the first thing I do when I lose a follower.

You've also mentioned you've checked your houses. Which ones?

Have you checked Hjerim, the house in Windhelm? [That's where he first appears](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Calder#Interactions), after you've purchased the home. He can also be found in the Sky Haven Temple if you are a Blade.

How long did you wait? If you told the follower to wait somewhere, he should get bored after a full day and then return home to Windhelm.

Since you are playing on Xbox and cannot use console commands, you can also try saving to a new slot, restarting the game, and then reloading the save.

Comment: I waited about 4 days and yes I have checked hjerim

Comment: Do you have Hearthfire and have you built a homestead? He may be stationed at one of them.

Comment: Yes, yes and no he's not in there since I already checked it

Comment: Are you able to load an older save where the follower is still nearby? Even if you don't revert to this save, it might at least help you track down where you last saw him.

Comment: Must I wait with the wait function or normal game time

Comment: You should be able to use the wait function.

Comment: Sadly I'm not able to load an older save since those saves got deleted and replaced with new saves

Comment: Another thought: Are you a Blade? If so, Calder might be found at the Sky Haven Temple.

Comment: I don't think I am since I have not yet gotten jurgens horn

Comment: Are you currently on an active "Rescue" radiant quest? He might be the target for this and is tied up in a cave somewhere.

Comment: No it does not look like it

Comment: Is it possible that he was left in battle by one of the imperial towers during the "liberation of skyrim" quest

Comment: You are absolutely sure that Calder was your previous follower? Can you visit your other homes or towns where you are Thane and double-check that there isn't a different NPC following you?

Comment: You could go to each tower and check, but if he was told to wait in any of those locations, he should still have eventually gone home after enough time.

Comment: Well Lydia is my steward and my house is on falkreath so the only other place I am a thane at is windhelm

Comment: Do you know which towers it was?

Comment: Nvm I found him he was at the tower thank you for your help and time